# Why do I get "instantiation of variable ... required here, but no definition is available" for static double variable, but not for int?

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm compiling this program:

```
template<int N> struct Foo {
  static const double value;
};

int main() {
  auto const& value = Foo<1>::value;
}
```

Compiler output head:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 ./main.cpp  -o main
./main.cpp:6:31: warning: instantiation of variable 'Foo<1>::value' required here, but no definition is available [-Wundefined-var-template]
  auto const& value = Foo<1>::value;
                              ^
./main.cpp:2:23: note: forward declaration of template entity is here
  static const double value;
                      ^
./main.cpp:6:31: note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to suppress this warning if 'Foo<1>::value' is explicitly instantiated in another translation unit
  auto const& value = Foo<1>::value;
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/V5-2Lh

If I change `double` to `int`, that warning goes away.

Is there a reason for this in the C++ spec, or is this LLVM being inconsistent?

Comment: You need to initialize the static variable.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no diagnostic required for in the standard (but I won't put my hand into fire for...). So it's nice of llvm to issue one at all... The last sentence appears contradicting to me, though: If there's already a definition in *another* compilation unit, adding one here would result in double definition. Considering that the definition occurring in another CU actually is not uncommon I'd even consider the warning inappropriate...

Comment: @Aconcagua it's saying to add a declaration, not a definition

Comment: Presumably the difference in warnings has to do with the fact that integer constants can be defined in the class definition even without `constexpr`.

Comment: @M.M Good point, but then the hint is even more worthless. The *declaration* is already given inside the class...

Comment: @M.M it's asking for a definition ("instantiation of variable") or a statement that it is defined elsewhere.